# window['$variable' + 1] and Jquery not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help. window + jquery not working.

Work:

```
var $q = 1;
console.log(window['$q']); // 1
```

Not work:

```
$(function() {
var $q = 1;
console.log(window['$q']); // undefined
});
```

Help

Comment: It's because in the second example you're declaring `$q` within the scope of the jQuery ready event handler function, not the scope of the `window`. Also note that having global variables isn't a great idea in the first place

Comment: `window.$q = 1;` should work...

Comment: how is this related to this part in the question title - `window['$variable' + 1]`